# How to reference right-clicked object in WPF Context Menu item click event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, contextmenu

In WPF application there is a `Grid` with a number of objects (they are derived from a custom control). I want to perform some actions on each of them using context menu:

```
   <Grid.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
       <MenuItem  Name="EditStatusCm" Header="Change status" Click="EditStatusCm_Click"/>
     </ContextMenu>                   
   </Grid.ContextMenu>
```

But in the event handler I cannot get know which of the objects was right-clicked:

```
    private void EditStatusCm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyCustControl SCurrent = new MyCustControl();
        MenuItem menu = sender as MenuItem;
        SCurrent = menu.DataContext as MyCustControl; // here I get a run-time error
        SCurrent.Status = MyCustControl.Status.Sixth;
    }
```

On that commented line Debugger says: ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

Please help, what is wrong in my code?

**Edited (added):**

I tried to do the same, using **Command** approach:

I declared a `DataCommands` Class with `RoutedUICommand Requery` and then used `Window.CommandBindings`

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
  <CommandBinding Command="MyNamespace:DataCommands.Requery" Executed="RequeryCommand_Executed"></CommandBinding>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

XAML of MenuItem now looks like:

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
 <ContextMenu>
  <MenuItem  Name="EditStatusCm" Header="Change status"  Command="MyNamespace:DataCommands.Requery"/>
 </ContextMenu>                   
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

And event handler looks like:

```
    private void RequeryCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IInputElement parent = (IInputElement)LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)sender);
        MyCustControl SCurrent = new MyCustControl();
        SCurrent = (MuCustControl)parent;
        string str = SCurrent.Name.ToString();// here I get the same error
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
```

But debugger shows the same run-time error: ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

What is missing in my both approaches?

How I should reference right-clicked object in WPF Context Menu item click event handler?

Comment: I tried using Command approach as more WPF-ish, but got the same error. I edited my question and added steps of my Command approach attempt. My understanding of how to get the clicked object reference is missing something in both cases

Answer (score 35, accepted):

note the CommandParameter

```
<Grid Background="Red" Height="100" Width="100">
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem 
                Header="Change status" 
                Click="EditStatusCm_Click"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

and use it in the handler to figure out which Grid it is

```
    private void EditStatusCm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
        if (mi != null)
        {
            ContextMenu cm = mi.CommandParameter as ContextMenu;
            if (cm != null)
            {
                Grid g = cm.PlacementTarget as Grid;
                if (g != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(g.Background); // Will print red
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update:**
If you want the menuitem handler to get to the Grid's children instead of the Grid itself, use this approach

```
<Grid Background="Red" Height="100" Width="100">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="TextBlockContextMenu">
            <MenuItem 
                Header="Change status" 
                Click="EditStatusCm_Click"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}" />
        </ContextMenu>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TextBlockContextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Row0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="Row1" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Just replace the TextBlocks with whatever your custom object type is. Then in the event handler, replace `Grid g = cm.PlacementTarget as Grid` with `TextBlock t = cm.PlacementTarget as TextBlock` (or whatever your custom object type is).

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that in the end (I mean your code example) we get "g"-the reference to Grid (where my Context Menu XAML declaration is placed), but I need the reference to clicked object which is inside the Grid (inside the Grid I have hundreds of similar objects, each of them can be right-clicked to get a context menu).

Comment: instead of putting the contextmenu on the grid itself, put it on the Grid's children.

Comment: Performance note:  Readers should note that the `CommandParameter` binding is not actually necessary here, since `e.Source` can be used instead.  The only essential requirement for this to work is that each element have its own `ContextMenu`.  Although `CommandParameter` is significantly less efficient than using `e.Source` because of the bindings, you could easily argue that it is more elegant and therefore worth the lower efficiency.

Answer (score 6):

By binding the Data Context like so in the xaml:

```
ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource=    {RelativeSource Self}}">
```

You can then do this:

```
private void Context_MenuClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var menuItem = e.Source as MenuItem;

   MyDoStuffFunction(menuItem.DataContext);
}
```

The data context will be bound to the object that was clicked to open the ContextMenu.

I got it from a codeproject article at this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162784/WPF-ContextMenu-Strikes-Again-DataContext-Not-Upda

Answer (score 2):

`menu = sender as MenuItem` will be null if the sender is not a MenuItem or a derived class thereof. Subsequently trying to dereference menu will blow up.

It's likely that your sender is a Menu or ContextMenu or a ToolStripMenuItem or some other form of menu item, rather than specifically being a MenuItem object. Use a debugger breakpoint to stop the code here and examine the sender object to see exactly what class it is.

Comment: I used a debugger breakpoint on this line and it says about "sender" Type as follows: "sender   {System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem Header:Change status Items.Count:0} object {System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem}"

Comment: It is possible that you get that event from several items, some of which are MenuItems (like the one you've caught in the debugger) and some of which are not (like the one causing your crash). If you use if (menu != null) around your processing code, you can stop it trying to process any events from non-MenuItem objects, which may help. Or it is actually crashing on the next line, and it is menu.DataContext that is not a MyCustControl object. Just single step through with the debugger and look at each value till you find out which one is null.

Comment: menu = sender as MenuItem 
does not work because by default MenuItem is a class in System.Windows.Forms,
however it works like
sender as System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem;

Answer (score 2):

For [RoutedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs_members.aspx)

- *RoutedEventArgs.source* is the reference to the object that raised the event
- *RoutedEventArgs.originalSource* is the reporting source as determined by pure hit testing, before any possible Source adjustment by a parent class.

So .Sender should be the answer. But this depends on how the menuitems are added and bound

See this [answer collection](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/634fe346-9ff9-448e-bbca-bba2ffa8740c/) and choose the method that will work for you situation!

Comment: Thanks for "answer collection" link. Certianly many ways to skin the cat. You think Microsoft would have made this cleaner by now!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be checking `RoutedEventArgs.Source` instead of `sender`?

Answer (score 1):

You had two different problems.  Both problems resulted in the same exception, but were otherwise unrelated:

**First problem**

In your first approach your code was correct and ran well except for the problem here:

```
SCurrent.Status = MyCustControl.Status.Sixth;
```

The name "Status" is used both as a static member and as an instance member.  I think you cut-and-pasted the code incorrectly into your question.

It may also be necessary to add the following after `MenuItem menu = sender as MenuItem;`, depending on your exact situation:

```
  if(menu==null) return;
```

**Second problem**

In your second approach you used "sender" instead of "e.Source".  The following code works as desired:

```
private void RequeryCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)    
{    
    IInputElement parent = (IInputElement)LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)e.Source);
      // Changed "sender" to "e.Source" in the line above
    MyCustControl SCurrent = new MyCustControl();    
    SCurrent = (MuCustControl)parent;    
    string str = SCurrent.Name.ToString();// Error gone
    MessageBox.Show(str);    
}
```

**Final Note**

Note:  There is no reason at all to bind `CommandParameter` for this if you use the commanding approach.  It is significantly slower and takes more code.  `e.Source` will always be the source object so there is no need to use `CommandParameter`, so use that instead.

Comment: Ray, in case of using your last piece of code I get a debugger error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type 'MyCustControl'. It seems that e.sourse points not to the clicked object but to the Grid (where my Context Menu XAML declaration is placed).

Comment: Interesting.  I remember I actually cut-and-pasted your code into a project and tried it.  I think I may have pasted the ContextMenu into a template without thinking about it instead of attaching it to the Grid, since it obviously wouldn't be possible for it to work as desired if the ContextMenu were attached to the Grid.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:-

XAML:-

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu x:Name="AddColumnsContextMenu" MenuItem.Click="AddColumnsContextMenu_Click">
</ContextMenu>
```

</DataGrid.ContextMenu>

For adding menu items:-

```
foreach (String s in columnNames)
{
var item = new MenuItem { IsCheckable = true, IsChecked = true ,Header=s};
AddColumnsContextMenu.Items.Add(item);
}
```

And here comes the listener:-

```
private void AddColumnsContextMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem mi = e.Source as MenuItem;
    string title = mi.Header.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("Selected"+title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to use:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    MenuItem menuItem        = e.Source as MenuItem;
    ContextMenu parent       = menuItem.Parent as ContextMenu;
    ListBoxItem selectedItem = parent.PlacementTarget as ListBoxItem;
}
```