# WPF Get the referenced item from a ContextMenu on a ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a `ListView` with `ContextMenu` on each `ListViewItem` that has `Click` event,
how can I detect in the event handler which Item was clicked in this ContextMenu?
I need the item `ID`.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
```

.
.
.

```
 <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="tv:TreeListViewItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Open in current tab" Click="MenuItemCurrentTab_Click"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Open in new tab" Click="MenuItemNewTab_Click"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Grid.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032832/how-to-reference-right-clicked-object-in-wpf-context-menu-item-click-event-handle) thread..

Following the same way as the answer from the link you would

```
<Grid.ContextMenu> 
    <ContextMenu> 
        <MenuItem Header="Open in current tab"
                  Click="MenuItemCurrentTab_Click"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}"/>
```

...

```
private void MenuItemCurrentTab_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if (menuItem != null)
    {
        ContextMenu parentContextMenu = menuItem.CommandParameter as ContextMenu;
        if (parentContextMenu != null)
        {
            ListViewItem listViewItem = parentContextMenu.PlacementTarget as ListViewItem;
        }
    } 
}
```

**UPDATE**

Add this to get the parent ListViewItem from the Grid

```
public T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject child = childObject as DependencyObject;
    while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }
    return child as T;
}

private void MenuItemCurrentTab_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if (menuItem != null)
    {
        ContextMenu parentContextMenu = menuItem.CommandParameter as ContextMenu;
        if (parentContextMenu != null)
        {
            Grid grid = parentContextMenu.PlacementTarget as Grid;
            ListViewItem listViewItem = GetVisualParent<ListViewItem>(grid);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I triedit and since I have a control template, instead of the listview item parentContextMenu.PlacementTarget retrieves for me the grid that inside the control template :(

Answer (score 3):

```
    private void MenuItemCurrentTab_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)e.Source;
        ContextMenu menu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)menu.PlacementTarget;
        // do something with item
    }
```

But it's probably better idea to create single ContextMenu, give it proper name, and use it for all list view items.

Comment: I did what you wrote but menu.PlacementTarget retrieves grid and not the listview item and I didn't know what to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

A recurring problem, with many attempts to solve but all have their drawbacks. The accepted answer here, for instance, supposes that each `ListViewItem` has its own `ContextMenu`. This works but, especially with a larger number of list items, has a considerable cost in XAML complexity and can be slow. And really isn't necessary at all. If we only use a single `ContextMenu` on the `ListView` itself, some other solutions suggest to use

```
 <MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```

which seems to solve the problem at first sight (`PlacementTarget` points to the `ListView`, its `SelectedItem` points to the list item, so the menu item handler can use the `CommandParameter` to get the originating list item), but, unfortunately, fails if the `ListView` has multiple selection enabled (`SelectedItem` will point to one of the items selected but not necessarily the one currently clicked) or if we use `ListView.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` to disable the selection on right-click (which is, arguably, the only logical thing to do with multiple selections).

There is, however, an approach that has all the benefits:

- single `ContextMenu` on the `ListView` itself;
- works with all selection schemes, single, multiple, disabled;
- even with multiple selection, it will pass the currently hovered item to the handler.

Consider this `ListView`:

```
<ListView ContextMenuOpening="ListView_ContextMenuOpening">
  <ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="Menu1" Click="Menu1_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding Parent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </ContextMenu>
  </ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

The `CommandParameter` is used to pass the parent of the `MenuItem`, ie. the `ContextMenu` itself. But the main trick comes in the menu opening handler:

```
private void ListView_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e) {
  var menu = (e.Source as FrameworkElement).ContextMenu;
  menu.Tag = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
}
```

Inside this handler, we still know the original source of the event, the root `FrameworkElement` of the list item `DataTemplate`. Let's store it in the `Tag` of the menu for later retrieval.

```
private void Menu1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  if (sender is MenuItem menu)
    if (menu.CommandParameter is ContextMenu context)
      if (context.Tag is FrameworkElement item)
        if (item.DataContext is DataType data) {
          //process data
        }
}
```

In the menu click handler, we can look up the original `ContextMenu` we stored in the command parameter, from that we can look up the root `FrameworkElement` of the list item that we stored just before, and finally get the object stored in the list item (of type `DataType`).

Answer (score 0):

```
ListViewItem item = myListView.SelectedItem as ListViewItem;
```

Seems to work just fine as the item is selected when you right-click it.