# How to make right click Button Context menu in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF error logging app, where when a user enters a new connection string, a connection button is created and shown as stacked list on the sidebar.

I want to make a right click event on those connection buttons to show a Button context menu for **View, Edit, Delete**.

My **MainWindow.xaml** Sidebar grid is like this,

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="318*" />

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <StackPanel Name="listConnections" Grid.Column="0" Background="#4682b4" Margin="0,0,0,-0.2" >
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

And I am calling the `Stackpanel listConnections` in my **MainWindow.xaml.cs** like this

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    GetUserData();
    //Button to create new connection
    listConnections.Children.Add(new NewConnectionButton(this));
    this.Closed += new EventHandler(MainWindow_Close);
}
```

[Right-Click event WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776911/how-to-create-a-right-click-context-menu-for-a-button-in-wpf) 
I tried to follow this link to create the right click event, but it is not working out for me. Can someone please assist me in this please?

Comment: Before you get too deep in to learning WPF using code behind, consider learning the MVVM pattern.  WPF is *significantly* easier to use with MVVM.  It is a pretty big mental shift if you've never used it before though, so be prepared for a learning curve.  You will thank yourself later.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I am very new to WPF and it is hard to get my head around the .xaml and .xaml cs. But right now I am just stuck on finishing this final WPF project.

Answer (score 8):

What I'd do here would be the following:

- create context menu separately and assign it to every "connection" object on the UI
- handle `MenuItem.Click` clicks event for every menu item
- resolve the clicked item in a list and process it respectively

MVVM and all that is certainly good but this straightforward approach is at least good place to start:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Having CommandParameter is crucial here -->
        <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="View"
                      Click="View_OnClick"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit"
                      Click="Edit_OnClick"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                      Click="Delete_OnClick"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="318*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <StackPanel Name="listConnections" Grid.Column="0" Background="#4682b4" Margin="0,0,0,-0.2" >
                <Button Click="BtnAdd_OnClick">New Connection</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static Label FindClickedItem(object sender)
        {
            var mi = sender as MenuItem;
            if (mi == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var cm = mi.CommandParameter as ContextMenu;
            if (cm == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return cm.PlacementTarget as Label;
        }

        private void BtnAdd_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listConnections.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Content = "New Connection",
                ContextMenu = (ContextMenu)Resources["contextMenu"]
            });
        }

        private void View_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var clickedItem = FindClickedItem(sender);
            if (clickedItem != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Viewing: " + clickedItem.Content);
            }
        }

        private void Edit_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var clickedItem = FindClickedItem(sender);
            if (clickedItem != null)
            {
                string newName = "Connection edited on " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                string oldName = Convert.ToString(clickedItem.Content);
                clickedItem.Content = newName;
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Changed name from '{0}' to '{1}'", oldName, newName));
            }
        }

        private void Delete_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var clickedItem = FindClickedItem(sender);
            if (clickedItem != null)
            {
                string oldName = Convert.ToString(clickedItem.Content);
                listConnections.Children.Remove(clickedItem);
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Removed '{0}'", oldName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: about to click edit]

[image: after clicking on edit]

Hope this helps

Comment: P.S. kudos to [kenwarner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/55948/kenwarner) for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2052782/248406) regarding CommandParameter in MenuItem

Comment: I don't see how the contextMenu actually gets displayed on right-click.

Answer (score 6):

You should put a context menu inside the resources of the button, like this

```
<NewConnectionButton.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="connectionButtonContext"  StaysOpen="true">
        <MenuItem Header="Add" Click="InternalAddButton_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="InternalDeleteButton_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="InternalEditButton_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</NewConnectionButton.Resources>
```

This code should be inside the `NewConnectionButton` *UserControl*. In the *UserControl* C# code, subscribe to those events and expose them 
(`InternalAddButton_Click`, `InternalDeleteButton_Click`, `InternalEditButton_Click`) to who uses the *Button*. Then, subscribe to them in your `MainWindow`.