# Button ContextMenu not Appearing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a context menu on a button, which I have added in xaml as follows:

```
<Button Content="{Binding MaterialLabel}"
        Command="{Binding SwapCommand}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="RClickSwaps" ItemsSource="{Binding SwapList}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding targetMaterial.Component_Code}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RClickSwapCommand}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContentControl>
                                <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="2">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding targetMaterial.Component_Name}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

The Binding for the `UserControl` as a whole is to a view model which contains a collection (`SwapList`) of classes that contain the command and `TargetMaterial` properties for the context menu used above:

```
//Control View Model
public ObservableCollection<SwapMenuItem> SwapList { get; set; }

//... Some irrelevant Code excluded ...

SwapList = new ObservableCollection<SwapMenuItem>();
var swaps = new ObservableCollection<Raw_Materials>(await ComponentDataService.GET_MaterialSwaps(New_Material));
foreach (var item in swaps)
{
    SwapList.Add(new SwapMenuItem(item, this));
}
OnPropertyChanged("SwapList");
```

The `SwapMenuItem` itself contains the following properties and a command that look a bit like this:

```
public class SwapMenuItem : Observable
{
    public ComponentChangeViewModel ComponentChangeViewModel { get; set; }
    public Raw_Materials TargetMaterial { get; set; }
    public ICommand RClickSwapCommand {get;set;}

    public SwapMenuItem(Raw_Materials raw_Materials, ComponentChangeViewModel componentChangeViewModel)
    {
        ComponentChangeViewModel = componentChangeViewModel;
        TargetMaterial = raw_Materials;
    }

    private void Swap()
    {
        //The command actually calls this method, but I excluded the long winded code
    }
}
```

My problem is that the context menu does not appear when I right click the button, nothing happens at all. I am trying to work within the MVVM pattern, but am I missing some sort of event to make the context menu appear on right click? Most of the advice online does not use the context menu as part of `Button.Resources`, but this seems to be the best way to do it according to some ([for instance here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547647/how-to-make-right-click-button-context-menu-in-wpf/43547962)). None of these examples contain anything to make the context menu appear on right click, so I figured it must be there by default?

Why can I not make the context menu appear, even when there are values in the `ItemsSource` collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only define a context menu with a key in the resources. The `Button` does not automatically know that it should use it. You have to set this resource to the `ContextMenu` property of `Button`.

You can either use the `StaticResource` markup extension in element property syntax like this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding MaterialLabel}"
        Command="{Binding SwapCommand}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="RClickSwaps" ItemsSource="{Binding SwapList}">
            <!-- ...your context menu markup. -->
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.ContextMenu>
       <StaticResource ResourceKey="RClickSwaps"/>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Or you can set it in attribute syntax by using the `DynamicResource` markup extension. Note that `StaticResource` does not work here, as the resource `RClickSwaps` is defined later in XAML, so it cannot be resolved statically at this point.

```
<Button Content="{Binding MaterialLabel}"
        Command="{Binding SwapCommand}"
        ContextMenu="{DynamicResource RClickSwaps}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="RClickSwaps" ItemsSource="{Binding SwapList}">
            <!-- ...your context menu markup. -->
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

Of course you can also just assign the context menu directly, without `Resources`.

```
<Button Content="{Binding MaterialLabel}"
        Command="{Binding SwapCommand}">
   <Button.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding StringItems}">
         <!-- ...your context menu markup. -->
      </ContextMenu>
   </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Comment: Yes, so simple, but apparently missed out of a lot of the examples online, that only show the resources, assuming that the reader knows to also use it (which to be fair, I probably should have). This works perfectly - is there any particular reason to choose one option over another, or are they all totally equivalent?

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter They are not equivalent. I personally prefer to put context menus directly in controls (last example) or share them in a resource dictionary that is included upfront, thus making `StaticResource` also usable via attribute syntax. Using `DynamicResource` resolves the resource at runtime, which means the context menu might just not be there if it is not found and the application keeps running, while `StaticResource` will lead to an exception.